# download file from my server to client's local system in specific path without dialog box

Tags: javascript, java, asp.net, .net, .net-core

All I want is to download a file from my server to the client's local system in a specific path without a dialog box.

I am using the code bellow:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\filename.exe", bytes1);
```

But the error is:

> Access to the path 'D:\filename.exe' is denied.

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes` - is server-side C# code. It cannot "download ... to client's local system". The code tries to write to D: root on the server, which it does not have access to.

Comment: what is solution?

Comment: There isn't a solution.  If a browser allowed it, it would be a security-risk.  I certainly don't want websites saving files on my computer without a dialog box.